# Oracle database control files issues and problems?

Tags: oracle

I was given an assignment which asks me to answer the following questions:

1. What problems does the dba face with control files?
2. How does the dba analyze and get to know these problems?
3. What are the solutions and suggestions for solving these problems?

Comment: So, how did you solve your assignment?

Comment: why did I ask you in the first place?

Comment: It is frowned upon to do other people's homework for them.  If you tell us how you would answer the questions, people will be glad to discuss them and lead you to self-discovery.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96521/control.htm

Answer (score 0):

In short Control file keep the record of physical location of Datafile and it read the header of datafiles during start up phase.
Oracle RMAN default behaviour to take control files auto back up and in time to any physical corruption you can restore it from backup.